# Xamarin forms listview - show images full widh, auto height

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in Xamarin Forms and I have a requirement to maintain aspect ratio but also this:

1. When an image is taller than it is wide, show the image flush to the left and right with no margins, have the height be *auto*

When an image is wider than it is tall, the requirement is the same, but this works.  In the screenshot it shows how images currently render when they're taller than wide.  Changing the aspect property breaks the condition when it is wider than tall.  When I copy this template into a blank page, the image displays fine.  I think the issue is being able to set the height of each row in the listview to auto.  It may not be the issue though.  I'm using a SyncFusion listview for Xamarin

[image]

Here is the code for the item template of the listview:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ViewCell>
     <StackLayout Margin="0,10,0,10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <!-- Card Header -->
                <!-- Truncated for brevity -->
                </Grid>
                 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                         <!-- Card title -->
                         <!-- Truncated for brevity -->
                  </StackLayout>
                  <!-- Card Body -->
                  <StackLayout  BindingContextChanged="PostImageStackLayout_BindingContextChanged">
                  <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="postImageStackLayout" Margin="0,15,0,10">
                        <!-- Card article image -->
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" x:Name="postImage" CacheDuration="1" HeightRequest="300"
                            Source="{Binding MainIMageURL}" BindingContextChanged="PostImage_BindingContextChanged"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Margin="0,10,0,10" FadeAnimationEnabled="True" Aspect="AspectFit" >
                         <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                              <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PostImageTapped" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                          </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>                                           
                 </Grid>
     </StackLayout>
     <!--Likes and comment count-->
     <!-- Truncated for brevity -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put fix height on Grid Row where it have the image element. You can use the "auto" value.

```
<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
```

and change the Aspect to

> AspectFill

I use the collectionview from the latest Xamarin.Forms 4.3. Here is my sample code

**xaml**

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="ImagesCollectionView">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <ListItemsLayout ItemSpacing="20">
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <ItemsLayoutOrientation>Vertical</ItemsLayoutOrientation>    
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </ListItemsLayout>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>             

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                Source="{Binding .}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                LoadingPlaceholder="noimg.png"/>

                            <Label Text="label" 
                                   TextColor="Gray" 
                                   Opacity="0.8" 
                                   Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                   FontSize="Small"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

**c#**

```
    public MySecondView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ImagesCollectionView.ItemsSource = new List<string>()
        {
        "http://insidetema.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/170717100550_1_900x600.jpg"
        ,"https://informationng.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/bigstock_Happy_Business_People_With_Han_4049346.jpg"
        ,"http://www.blt.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Happy-Places.jpg"
        };
    }
```

> Output

[image]

Comment: The image is in a stacklayout, not a grid.  Changing to aspectfill clips the image.  The 'grid' references above in xaml are left over from when I tried putting all the elements in a grid with height auto.  Didn't work either

Comment: what does the code look like for this?  I'd like to try it

Comment: Thanks, Although the image takes up the full width, it is not as tall as it needs to be and it is also clipped.  (some of the image is missing)

Comment: If this sample is not working for your scope, please update your question with working images and the final ui result where you want to have.

Comment: that is already posted.  The problem is described above, all of the solutions suggested do not work

Comment: @Gold.strike hi, I'm not on the project anymore.  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can set the HeightRequest and WidthRequest of your image to -1 (then it'll fit all the space available)

Comment: Thanks but that made the image smaller